# Why different php session value in Chrome and FireFox?

Tags: php, ajax, session

set a session value to 10 by ajax.
In Chrome it will set back to ZERO. Why??
my.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["temp"] = 0; ?>


<div id="t">$_SESSION["temp"] = <?=$_SESSION["temp"]?> <br></div>
<br><input type="button" value="Plus 5" onclick="javascript:plusn(5);">
<script>
    function plusn(n) {
          $.ajax({
              url: 'myajax.php?n='+n,
              type: 'get',
              async: false,
              success:function(result){
                  $("#t").append(result)
              }
          });
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        plusn(10); //initial add 10
    })
</script>
```

myajax.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["temp"] += $_GET["n"];
exit('$_SESSION["temp"] = '.$_SESSION["temp"].'<br>');
?>
```

place here: https://cmbody.com/my.php
Please use different browsers to check it.
Chrome, Edge and Android cell phones get the wrong result;
Firefox and iPhone get the correct results.
P.S. same condition using COOKIE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
```

The browser tries to load the favicon from the same URL, as instructed. For that, it performs an additional request to the main PHP script. The differences happen because Firefox uses the cached page and Chrome-based browsers fetch a fresh copy:

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

Comment: I removed that line and everything work fine. How miraculous!

Answer (score 0):

It works correctly when I send it with a 1000 millisecond delay but this is not a correct solution I will continue to investigate.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
        plusn(10);
    },1000)
```

Comment: WOW! It works!! Thank you! 
(I think this maybe a bug, right?)

Comment: This probably just masks the problem (session is increased before it's reset).

Comment: make sense! :-)